# Have object being displaced, want to randomize time of displacement within set parameters, then loop that

Tags: c#, loops, random, unity-game-engine

I have a transformation (force applied moves object) happening initially, and then the user responds to it with the `DownArrow`. I want that initial `transform.up` to happen at random times within a set interval, and for that to loop over and over, so that the user can continue to respond to it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class thingBumps : MonoBehaviour {

public float thrust;
public Rigidbody rb;

void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.AddForce (transform.up * thrust, ForceMode.Impulse);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        rb.AddForce(-transform.up * thrust,ForceMode.Impulse);
}

}
```

I have tried Coroutines and also `InvokeRepeating` but I am having a very hard time and I have read every thread on the topic. I just want that first `transform.up` to repeat at random time intervals so the user can continue to respond to it (with their own `transform.up` transformation). Does anyone know how to do this?

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "random times within a set interval, and for that to loop"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you want to 'kick' object at random times. You can do that with a bit of scripting. Schedule next kick like this:

```
public class thingBumps : MonoBehaviour {

public float thrust = 10; // give some default value 
Rigidbody rb;// you dont need it to be public
float nextKick = 0;
float kickTimer = 0;
public float MinKickTime=1, MaxKickTime=10;//seconds

void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    nextKick = Random.Range(MinKickTime,MaxKickTime);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    kickTimer+=Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    if(kickTimer>nextKick)
    {
         rb.AddForce (transform.up * thrust, ForceMode.Impulse);
         kickTimer=0;
         nextKick = Random.Range(MinKickTime,MaxKickTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        rb.AddForce(-transform.up * thrust,ForceMode.Impulse);
}

}
```

Links:

- [Random.Range](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)
- [Time.fixedDeltaTime](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html)

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much, this works perfectly. This is also just a lesson in problem solving. This is not cookie cutter from the Unity documents. It is something creative of your own design that works. As a beginner programmer, I am very impressed by this. Thank you for your help today!